How to fix overlapping faces
I want to model a pen (with a special shape). To do this, I made the basic shape of the pen and put ellipses with a subdivision modifier and a shrinkwrap modifier on top. (I don't know if this is the efficient way to model the pen.) Now I'm faced with the problem that the ellipses overlap and the mesh flickers. I have tried clean up/merge by distance, but the mesh has either remained overlapping or holes have appeared at a higher threshold. What is the best way to remove the overlap and create a clean mesh?



Can you add a reference photo of what the pen is supposed to look like.

It's not clear what you're trying to do, for example why are you using another object or mesh for this part?
You could begin with a cylinder, subdivide its top face:

Move up these vertices:

Extrude up the whole face, scale 0 on Z:

Then RMB > LoopTools > Circle:

Extrude again and scale down the tip:

Bevel all the edges that you want to keep sharp:

Give it a Subdivision Surface modifier and RMB > Shade Smooth:

Cut the top with knife:

Give it 2 materials:

